# Given sample space and distribution, how to construct a random variable with the same distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space, $\sigma(S)$ is generated by metric topology of $S$.$([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \bf{P})$ is the sample space. $\bf P'$ is a probability measure on $(S,\sigma(S))$. Is it guarenteed that there exists a random variable $X: [0,1] \to S$ such that ${\bf{P'}}= {\bf{P}} \circ X^{-1}$?

---

**Added:** This question is motivated by a paragraph (See [here](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=oGUET9JBytEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=roger+myerson&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=NQ84UtzaNISViQeloYHAAg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=a%20probability%20model%20or%20a%20state-variable%20model&f=false) on googlebooks) in Roger Myerson's *Game Theory: Analysis of Conflict*:

[image]

I want to know whether these two approaches are equivalent in some general occasions.